# Response.Write in foreach live update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, loops

I have a foreach which imports data to our CMS. Now I want to display a message with the current row info after every run. I don't want that the information is comming after the whole procedure. The message have to come step by step.

```
foreach()
{
    // my import procedure

    Response.Write("row x updated");
}
```

How can I do that? Can I do that with Response.Flush? Or do I have to make it else?

Best regards
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set this once before you loop:

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Then call `Response.Flush()` every time you want to update the client.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Flush() seems to be the way to go. Otherwise, the responses are buffered.